# could jQuery :contains() use wildcards '_' like SQL? (match exactly N character)

Tags: jquery, wildcard, contains

could jQuery :contains() use wildcards  '_' 
like SQL as below?

```
%1___A%
```

(between 1~A, match exactly 3 random character)

--
:contains('1___A') =>definitely wrong example

Comment: From sizzle docs https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#additions I found no expression seems allowed.

Comment: [Question is unclear,read how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)